# TeamCity runner that edits GitHub PR description

Tags: github, teamcity, github-api

Or a runner that allows general API calls to GitHub. I want to provide a link to a TeamCity artifact in the PR. Currently I'm doing that with a status check but it's annoying that status checks get hidden when they are all passing, plus they are always down at the bottom. So instead I'd like to add the artifact link at the end of the PR description. It's hard to google for this because all my searches point at calling the TeamCity API from GitHub instead of vice versa.

Comment: Could you describe your workflow? Do you need to edit some PR (if so, how to find out which), or do you want to create PR automatically?

Comment: The build config is running on a PR branch (e.g. `pull/1234/head`). The runner would only run if it could parse the PR from the branch name. And yes, I would expect it to edit the PR's initial comment to add some dynamic content configured in the runner. It's an important difference to the status checks because the status checks go with a specific commit rather than a PR/branch. But it should definitely be do-able. I've already tested it with manual curl commands (after I made this question).